# How to get xml attribute values using Document builder factory

Tags: java, xml, document

How to get attribute values by using the following code i am getting ; as output for msg . I want to print MSID,type,CHID,SPOS,type,PPOS values can any one solve this issue .

```
String xml1="<message MSID='20' type='2635'>"
        +"<che CHID='501' SPOS='2'>"
        +"<pds type='S'>"
        +"<position PPOS='S01'/>"
        +"</pds>"
        +"</che>"
        +"</message>";

InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml1));

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.parse(source);

XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

String msg = xpath.evaluate("/message/che/CHID", document);
String status = xpath.evaluate("/pds/position/PPOS", document);

System.out.println("msg=" + msg + ";" + "status=" + status);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@` in your XPath for an attribute, and also your path specifier for the second element is wrong:

```
String msg = xpath.evaluate("/message/che/@CHID", document);
String status = xpath.evaluate("/message/che/pds/position/@PPOS", document);
```

With those changes, I get an output of:

```
msg=501;status=S01
```

Comment: Using xpath will effect performance than using elements.getattribute

Comment: @VBS: Well I was just going by the code that you'd already provided... I assumed you wanted that to be fixed rather than changing approach entirely. Your question doesn't mention performance at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Document.getDocumentElement()` to get the root element and `Element.getElementsByTagName()` to get child elements:

```
Document document = db.parse(source);

Element docEl = document.getDocumentElement(); // This is <message>

String msid = docEl.getAttribute("MSID");
String type = docEl.getAttribute("type");

Element position = (Element) docEl.getElementsByTagName("position").item(0);
String ppos = position.getAttribute("PPOS");

System.out.println(msid); // Prints "20"
System.out.println(type); // Prints "2635"
System.out.println(ppos); // Prints "S01"
```

Comment: I believe using xpath is slower, but as long as you work with small XMLs you shouldn't be concerned with performance.